# Android - AuthUI - firebase doesn't work when login by facebook

Tags: android, firebase, facebook-graph-api, firebase-authentication

Welcome everybody,
A have an application in android studio, 
I use the firebase, but when the user login
by AuthUI to login by (facebook or google)

```
    try {
        startActivityForResult(
                AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setAvailableProviders(
                                Arrays.asList(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build(),
                                        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build(),
                                        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER).build()
                                ))
                        .build(),
                RC_SIGN_IN);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

and the user success login then
the firebase doesn't work.
When a user logout,

```
    AuthUI.getInstance()
            .signOut(this)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    // user is now signed out
                    // finish();
                }
            });
```

the firebase start working normally

Comment: when does firebase not work?

Comment: while user is logged in by facebook or google

Answer (score 0):

I use this for my google sign in and out. works great! You will of course have to adapt for your resources. If this does not fix the problem, then you may have library dependency issue. let me know

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        View.OnClickListener {

```
private static final String TAG = "GoogleActivity";
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

// [START declare_auth]
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
// [END declare_auth]

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Views


    // Button listeners
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.buttonGoChat).setOnClickListener(this);


    // [START config_signin]
    // Configure Google Sign In
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    // [END config_signin]

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    // [START initialize_auth]
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    // [END initialize_auth]
}

// [START on_start_check_user]
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    updateUI(currentUser);
}
// [END on_start_check_user]

// [START onactivityresult]
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } else {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            updateUI(null);
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }
    }
}
// [END onactivityresult]

// [START auth_with_google]
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());


    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        updateUI(user);
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        updateUI(null);
                    }


                }
            });
}
// [END auth_with_google]

// [START signin]
private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
// [END signin]

private void signOut() {
    // Firebase sign out
    mAuth.signOut();

    // Google sign out
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                    updateUI(null);
                }
            });
}




private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {

    if (user != null) {

        findViewById(R.id.buttonGoChat).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {


        findViewById(R.id.buttonGoChat).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
    // be available.
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent go = new Intent();
    int i = v.getId();
    if (i == R.id.sign_in_button) {
        signIn();
    } else if (i == R.id.sign_out_button) {
        signOut();
    } else if (i == R.id.buttonGoChat){
        go.setClass(getApplicationContext(),ChatActivity.class);
        startActivity(go);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: But in my code I have no any line to login in firebase. I did login in firebase by clicking some options of menu in android studio.

Comment: I apologize but I dont think I am understanding the question. Are you trying to use firebase to login with google or facebook for your app?What do you mean by "clicking some options of menu in android studio?"